# Derived set or Limit points vs boundry points in Topology

Tags: general-topology

$(X,\tau)$ is a Topological space where as $\tau$ is the topology on $X$, and
$A \subseteq X$ is an arbitrary subset, $\overline{A}$ is the closure $A^{\circ}$ the interior and $\partial A$ is  the boundary of the set $A$.

Munkres topology defines the derived set of $A$, or a.k.a the set of all limit points of $A$ as:

$$A^{\prime}=\{x \in X \mid U \cap (A\backslash \{x\}) \neq \emptyset ,\ U \ \text{is an open subset containing} \  x \}.$$

Then in Munkres topology states that $\overline{A}=A \cup A^{\prime}$
which makes sense to me.

However if I compare that to the boudary of $A$ with

$$\partial A = \overline{A} \backslash A^{\circ}$$ which would lead me to

$$\overline{A}= A^{\circ} \cup \partial A = A \cup \partial A$$ since $A^{\circ} \subseteq A$. This brings me to the question of the relationship between $\partial A$ and $A^{\prime}$. I have read that they are not the same, but I don't understand how or why  and if they are not the same then I think one must contain the other one right ?
I don't know how to approach this does someone have an idea? Also there a third set which I am confused about the set of all contact points but that totally lost me.

Comment: Well it is certainly possible for $x$ to live in $A^\circ$ and $A’$ while it is obviously impossible for $x$ to live in $A^\circ$ and in the boundary, as this is a direct contradiction.

Comment: So what would that mean that $\partial A \subset A^{\prime}$ ?

Comment: Neither set inclusion is true. They are not comparable by the relation "'set inclusion".

Comment: @Xero33 no. A finite set has no interior points or limit points. That is, $A’=\emptyset$ while $$\partial A= \overline{A}\backslash A^\circ=A\backslash \emptyset=A$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to understand through example :

Consider $(\Bbb{R}, \tau_{std}) $ and $A=(0, 1) $

Then $A'=[0, 1]$

And $\partial(A) =\{0,1\}$

So it's clear that not all limit points are in the boundary.

---

Is $\partial(A)\subset A'$ ? **(N0)**

Choose $x\in \partial(A) $ and a open set $x\in U$ then $U\cap A\neq \emptyset$ and $U\cap (X\setminus A) \neq \emptyset$

But to be a  limit point of $A$ , $U$ have to contain a point of $A$ other than $x$.

$U$ may not contain such point.

For an example choose $A=\{0,1\}$ . Then both $0, 1$ are boundary points as any open interval containg $0$ intersect both $A$ and $\Bbb{R}\setminus A$ but none of them are limit points.

Task: A finite subset of $\Bbb{R}$ can't have any limit point.

---

Neither way set inclusion true.